# How to update an Android widget when the screen is turned On/Off?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, widget

I've written a battery monitor widget that I can update when the screen is turned on using a background Service with BroadcastReceivers and an Alarm.  I can also stop updating when the screen is turned off.  However, the Service only runs until the system stops the background service.

1. I don't want to use a foreground service because the user does not need to be notified.
2. Always checking and restarting the background service does not seem like a good solution.
3. I don't think I can bind a service to a widget.  But, I'm new to this and still learning.

How do I get around this problem?  I started looking into WorkManager but haven't found what
I'm looking for.

Any suggestions to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a listener class to listen for android lock screen and unlock events，use broadcast to receive the state of screen.

```
 private class ScreenBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
private String action = null;

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        action = intent.Action;
        if (Intent.ActionScreenOn == action)
        { // screen on
            mScreenStateListener.onScreenOn();
        }
        else if (Intent.ActionScreenOff == action)
        { // screen off
            mScreenStateListener.onScreenOff();
        }
        else if (Intent.ActionUserPresent == action)
        { // unlock
            mScreenStateListener.onUserPresent();
        }
    }
}
```

For more code for the listener, you could refer to the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55014763/11850033

You could override the OnUpdate of `AppWidgetProvider`. And then trigger an onUpdate on your Widget.
[How to call onUpdate method of widget on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028646/how-to-call-onupdate-method-of-widget-on-button-click)

**Update：**

You could try to inprove the level of context.

```
 mContext.ApplicationContext.RegisterReceiver(mScreenReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: I created the Listener class from the link provided.  However, I get a runtime error when the Broadcast Receiver is being registered. `Android.Content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: 'BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents'`

Comment: I rechecked the listener again. It still work. You could try to use ApplicationContext. Please use the code in my update. It works as well.

Comment: I think this did it.  Thank you!

Comment: Haha, glad to help.